# Facing issue with calendar icon getting overlapped on another calendar popup when disabled

Tags: css, asp.net, css-selectors, styles

I am having multiple Ajax textbox calendars on the Page.
If everything is enbaled,calendar icon icon doesn't overlap or show on another calendar popup.
[image]

After clicking on Calendar Icon,

[image]

If control is disabled,then the
[image]

Now when user clicks on calendar above disabled one,image icon is getting overlapped
[image]

I tried with position and z-index but still its showing. Please let me know which style to apply to  not get overlap
Her is the css i tried

```
style="postion:relative;z-index:10000"
```

Calendar control view part:

```
<tr id="BeginDate"  runat="server">
        <td class="pboldfont" style="width: 5%;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblBeginDate" runat="server"  />
        </td>
        <td class="ps-setwidth" style="width: 30%;">
            &nbsp;<label  ID="lblBeginDate" runat="server" Text="Begin Date"  LabelForControl="txtBeginDate"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ps-controls" style="width: 65%;">&nbsp;
        <asp: txtcalendar style="position: relative; z-index: 0;" ID="txtBeginDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" DataFieldName="RequestedBeginDate" IsRequiredField="true" EnableClientScript="true"  CalendarMask="99/99/9999" EnableTheming="True"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `z-index` property to your icon astyle?

Comment: I tried adding to row, control but it did not work. Please suggest if there is any style that push icon to back.

Comment: But did you set the icon to a lower z-index value then the dropdown? Elements with lover z-index value are getting pushed back by the elements with higher z-index value

Comment: If you did can you post some more code so i can check it for the problem?

Comment: I tried setting above calendar  with higher index  and with lower index of current one, but issue still exists. Please let me know if there are ay styles which will make calendar icon stay behind

Comment: @AMDI so were clear did you set the z-index of the dropdown to a higher value than the icon?